# SPA Navigate and call action after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

TDLR; I have a todo SPA and I want to navigate a user from the create todo page to the todo page, and open relevant modal (I have the specific modal type on the create todo page)

The user is located on this route while creating new todo:

```
/todo/create
```

and after the user clicks save, I want to navigate him to this route:

```
/todo/:id
```

and then open a modal.

but, I don't won't to open the modal every-time a user enters the todo page,
and I have few modals, each one related to the todo the user created.
I have the open modal function on the create todo page.

```
const CreateTodoPage = () => {
  const onCreateTodo = async (todo) => {
    const savedTodo = await saveTodo(todo)
    await navigateToTodoPage(savedTodo.id)
    openModal(savedTodo) // This line won't work 
 }

 //FORM - on submit calls onCreateTodo
}
```

```
const useTodoQuery = () => {
  const {data, ...rest} = useQuery(['todo', todoId], async () => {
    if (todoId) {
      return await getTodo(todoId)
    }
    return null;
  })

  return {data, ...rest}
}
```

```
  const todoMutation = useMutation(
    ['todo'],
    getUpdatedTodo,
    {onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['todo', todoId])}
  );
```

I want to navigate it after the onSuccess to the specific todo page and open relevant modal to the todo.

any ideas?

Comment: Use a `try / finally` block. The finally block always runs, even if the function has returned in the try block. Maybe this will work for your use case.